# Error: ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

```
float App::fresnelReflectTerm(float etaPos, float etaNeg, float cos_theta_i)
{
float theta_i;
theta_i = acos(cos_theta_i);
    ...
```

This generates an "ambiguous call to overloaded function error" and says that there are four options:

```
float acos(float fValue)
double acos(double _X)
float acos(float _X)
long double acos(long double _X)
```

I suspect that the problem is that the first and third both take a float arg and return a float value. But can anyone give me a hint about how I might determine (I'm using Visual Studio) where those four functions came from, so that I can eliminate the duplication, for instance? Or perhaps just give me a hint on how to get around this problem.

Comment: What includes are you using in this project? Math.h and GenericMathTemplateLibrary?

Comment: I would start with theta_i = acos((float)cos_theta_i); just to see if that would fake the compiler out, if that got me nowhere fall back on theta_i = (float)acos((double)cos_theta_i);

Comment: Thanks. For now, I already discovered Tim's idea (the first one, too -- it didn't work), so I'm off and running.

Comment: As for "what includes are you using?", that's hard to answer: it uses a big library which has about a thousand includes, and I don't have the heart to look through every one, which is why I was hoping VS might be able to tell me. :)

Comment: In visual studio, go to view->output.  Go to the "Error List" you've been looking at and double click the error you mentioned. Now look at the output pane, and it should show the full and complete text of the error message.  Doubleclick any line with a filename and it will take you to the exact line of code with thte function(s) in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press F12 on that function.

**Update**

Based on comments from the OP, the problem was due to a definition of `acos` being brought in from `G3D::`. Using [std::acos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos) as opposed to `acos` will remove the ambiguity.

Comment: @John so what was the root problem?

Comment: The root problem was the two functions with signatures `float acos(float)`. It turns out that one of them was `G3D::acos`, a function in the library I was using; once I put on the `G3D::`, the compiler was able to distinguish. I actually *wanted* the *other* one, and still don't know how to get it, but I can manage with what I've got.

Comment: @John ummm, can't you just use [std::acos](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/acos)?

Comment: @Shafik: I'll bet that I could, except I had no idea that was allowed. (I'm an occasional C++ programmer at best, alas.) As usual, I've learned tons by asking a simple question. Thanks!

Comment: @John let me know if that works using `std:acos` for you if it does that should be edited into the answer as a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the file listing  compiler option in VS studio, so you will know which files are include during compiling, see this msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdkef6tk.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I'll file that away for later use, when I'm sure it'll come up.